# Is there a difference between an infinitely large spherical world and an infinite flat world?

Tags: science-based, alternate-worlds, nonspherical-worlds

Obviously, one is a sphere and one isn't, but would the inhabitants of either world be able to rule out the possibility that their world might actually be the other?

We humans knew that our world was spherical because of its curvature, but the larger the sphere the less the curvature of its surface so it stands to reason that in an infinitely large sphere there should be no curvature (or rather it is infinitely small and indistinguishable from none).

Since they can't coexist with infinitely large worlds, assume that either there are no celestial bodies (sun, stars, other planets etc.) or that they depend on the location of the observer (there will always be a sun visible exactly above one's head, or perhaps the world has a luminous "ceiling" above the atmosphere)

Assume no space travel but arbitrarily precise measuring instruments and arbitrarily high resources dedicated towards finding out whether their world is a sphere or a plane.

Assume earth-like conditions (gravity etc.), on the sphere gravity will pull towards the center, on the plane it will pull down.

Comment: As neither is real, difference is only philosophical.

Comment: Is there movement of the Sun at all? Or changes in the 'luminous' ceiling'?

Comment: @Mołot It's not philosophical - it's hypothetical. Like almost every other question on this site.

Comment: Can you define "infinitely large spherical world"? I'm having *a lot* of trouble envisioning this.

Comment: For either to exist, physics has to work in a completely different way - a flat world needs gravity to pull "down" and not towards centers, and an infinitely large sphere would have infinite gravity if its physics resembled our own.  Since the nature of physics is not specified, it is impossible to determine how one might use those physics to figure out which of the two worlds they are on.

Comment: @Aify A sphere with an infinite radius. The surface of said sphere would itself be infinite and have ininitely small curvature

Comment: How can you have a sphere if the radius is infinite? You wouldn't have a surface. By definition, a sphere has to have a surface, which means that there is a center, and therefore a fixed radius.

Comment: @IndigoFenix yes, that's why I had to throw out all celestial bodies. The physics in this universe are built in a manner such that they reproduce earth-like conditions. Think of it as a simulation in which the creators created the laws of physics to this purpose, if it helps

Comment: @Aify why not? Why can't the surface be infinitely distant from the center? The property that makes it a sphere is that it is *equally* distant from the center

Comment: Obviously more imagination is needed to handle this question. No-one can envisage infinity, but we have the conceptual tools to deal with it. So an infinite sphere will need an infinite radius. Have fun with a wicked hypothesis!

Comment: No, it's not "hypothetical". It can't exist, not physically, not theoretically. Infinity is not really a number, it's only something you can realistically use with things like $lim$

Comment: Things are complicated when infinities are considered. For example, the surface of a sphere of infinite radius has constant null curvature, which makes it look just lika a plane; any two great circles intersect in two points, but on a sphere with infinite radius those points are infinitely far... You may want to look at the considerations related to the [projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane).

Comment: The other property that makes a sphere a sphere is that each point on the surface is a constant distance from each other point. An "infinite" radius for any given point also means that each point is "infinitely far" relative to other points; if everything is infinitely far from each other, you don't have a sphere, you don't have a surface, you will only ever have a single molecule to act as a single point, unable to interact with anything and everything else because everything is infinitely far away from you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### If rocks become harder as you dig deeper, you are (probably) on a flat world.

My first thought was "dig".  Obviously, if you can dig through the "bottom" of the planet then you're living on a flat world.  But you don't even have to go that far.

Neither world makes sense according to physics, so we should presume this world is a simulation.  Therefore, we must take into account the rules of the simulation.  Either the simulation takes pressure into account, or it does not.

If the world is an infinitely large (or even merely "very" large) sphere and pressure exists, the pressure should increase as you go further down, becoming magma before finally turning into exploding plasma above an infinitely large neutronium layer that eventually builds up into an infinitely large singularity.  Now, since this concept makes no sense it is unclear what effect it would have on the world, but what is clear is that since this world is effectively a thin layer of rock sitting on top of an infinitely large exploding star it is probably not going to be habitable.

Since the world *is* habitable, it stands to reason that, if the rock *is* infinitely deep, pressure is *not* being simulated.  That means that the ground should not become harder as you go down, but remain a uniform, infinitely large rock-filled space throughout.  This also means no volcanic activity, which means no metamorphic (or igneous) rocks.

A flat world, on the other hand, *can* have normal pressure without becoming uninhabitable, since there is a limit to how high the pressure becomes, and this limit is probably above the point where fusion is initiated and the planet becomes a star.  Therefore, pressure *can* increase as you go down, allowing the flat world to have normal, Earth-like geography up until you reach the bottom.  Below this point - the "bedrock", so to speak - there is effectively nothing.  Therefore, if pressure increases as you go down, - indicated by the presence of igneous or metamorphic rocks - you are living on a flat world.

Comment: *"If pressure increases as you go down, - indicated by the presence of igneous or metamorphic rocks - you are living on a flat world."* but if it **doesn't** increase, it may again just be that pressure is not simulated, as in the spherical case. Further, in the spherical case, since it **is** a simulation (by your logic), the simulation of pressure may reach a limit at some point well before (or just before) neutronium or a singularity: Once pressure and heat are sufficient to ensure further digging is impossible, the simulation could stop there! Thus digging tells us nothing either way.

Comment: @Amadeus True, it isn't *proof*, but it is the assumption one would make using Occam's Razor and the Cosmological Principle. A pressure limit above that of a singularity at an arbitrary point within an infinitely large sphere suggests an additional law of physics we have no reason to believe exists, and therefore we should presume it does not unless we have evidence to the contrary.

Comment: You weren't talking about laws of physics, you were talking about a simulation; in which we can make the laws as arbitrary as we want. You posit the simulators must and did violate the laws of physics to be on a sphere: They could as easily violate the laws of physics on a flat world. You can't posit they *must* do it on one, and *must not* do it on the other! That is illogical; The densities they create on the sphere could just as easily be duplicated on the flat world; and then also be equally infinitely deep.

Answer (score 3):

## Is there a difference?

**Not by any practical measure.**

A planet with infinite curvature will curve if you manage to go infinitely far: it bends around a point infinitely far away, which is someplace! A flat surface, however, will stay flat, no matter how infinitely far you go.

Infinity is a very big idea, though, and we note that us mortals (and certainly the scientific and engineering mortals) do not deal with infinities anywhere except in our minds and through mathematical constructs. Sometimes we call things "practically infinite" to make life easier, but infinities is still something we do not deal in. Anyone living on this infinite-something-shape place, assuming similar physics to our own, would not be able to tell the difference.

Comment: As a side note, and therefore a comment: there are some interesting things that could happen in this world, like constant gravity no matter how high up you are (much like the E-field of an infinitely large plate stays constant no matter how far the test charge is from it). Neat to think about, terrible to actually live in!

Comment: Can you be sure: "terrible to actually live in!" Why it might be infinitely nice. I like the constant gravity idea. It would really ruin space travel. Would the curvature of space, as in General Relativity, be reflected in spacetime around either the infinite plane or the infinite sphere? The notion that mass might be infinite too in either case is a worry.

Answer (score 2):

## NO.

They cannot tell. No matter how sensitive their instruments are, there is a limit to the sensitivity of any instrument, and by claiming the world is infinite, any change in curvature (or direction of gravitational pull) is infinitely small, and beneath the measurement sensitivity of any finite device.

## YES.

Since we have already introduced in this story magical infinities; we might as well say the finite instrument is infinitely sensitive, so of course in a matter of a few yards it can detect the infinitely slight change of angle in the directional vector of gravitational pull, and with a series of such measurements conclude it is on an infinite sphere.

## Who is Measuring, Again?

In the setup of this question, other planets and stars cannot coexist with this planet because it is infinite in extent. Well neither can space, air, or inhabitants, for the same reasoning! If I stand on a planet, my eyes are six feet above its surface. How is my head, held six feet above the surface of the planet, any different than a moon or another planet? It is not. By the rules in the setup, if the size of the planet prohibits anything else from being in space due to its "infinity" then it prohibits air, inhabitants, or anything at all from existing upon it. By the rules of mathematical induction *it cannot even have a surface* because such a boundary divides one space from another (say inside the sphere from outside the sphere) which violates the premise that it is infinite.

### Which means...

Of the two options given, only the flat world can actually have inhabitants, air, sky. They cannot be on an infinite sphere and also exist, but they *could* be on an infinite plane and exist.

Alternatively, they could be on an infinite surface that happens to be flat in their observable region; but on some unimaginable (but finite) scale undulates or curves. If they are locally flat, then even infinitely precise instruments would not measure any curvature. (Understanding that "locally flat" could mean flat for millions of light years in any compass direction.) (Also, the same could not be true on a sphere, or it would no longer be a sphere.)